# haven't done ...yet?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I am reading one of the stories in an article from 1843 Magazine. The title is "Suffering from shortages? How to survive without puppies, fake tan or IKEA." The title of this story is "Confession of an IKEA Obsessive".

In this part of story, the writer talks about her relationship with IKEA. During the pandemic, IKEA's website broke down and many service was a mess.

> For me, it was the breaking of ikea that forced me to assess whether I could really handle dismantling capitalism as we know it. Was I just a phoney who could afford to hold my au courant views because they’ll never be more than castles in the air (furnished by faux diy flat-pack furniture)?
> I don’t know. But I haven’t gone to pick up Mackapär**...yet.**

Is there any connotation here by using an ellipsis? What's the difference if there is no ellipsis?

Comment: 'ellipsis' is made when the information should be protected by any relevant law or the writer doesn't want to disclose the information. There is no significant connotation.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like the writer is simply drawing attention to the word **yet**. There's nothing obvious that is missing or redacted there.  Mackapär is a series of products from IKEA. So, I don't think it's being used as an actual ellipsis would be used, or for anything in particular here. Maybe a long pause for dramatic effect?  It might have been better to use a long dash — like this.

Answer (score 1):

Not so much an ellipis, rather this is a dramatic pause.  In speech you would imagine a speaker pausing for a longer than normal time, for rhetorical purposes.  It makes the twist so much more effective if there is a pause.

Anyway see https://writetouch.ca/speechwriting/pausing-for-effect-seven-reasons-pauses-enhance-your-speeches-and-presentations-and-eight-ways-to-ace-them/ and read about the different uses of pauses in speech.